# Expressions in Margin - Visual Studio RDLC Report

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, Web Forms project. I'm trying to insert expression in the Margins of the RDLC file.
Today I can insert expressions in the font size, text align, padding, and other options.

Anyone know how, and if, I can insert expressions in the Margins of my RDLC?
I will do this for my clients. So they can personalize reports as they like.

Comment: I think we can use something like ReportViewer.LocalReport.GetDefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this using the .render expression!